# ZFS send/recv on Ubuntu Server 14 - Oh, where did my data go?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, zfs

I've been trying to figure out a method to replicate snapshots created by `zfs-auto-snap` from our primary data center to a remote server, both running Ubuntu Server 14 with the latest ZFS-FUSE.

Here's my local ZFS:

`NAME                    USED   AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT`
`zfs_pool01/data         4.47T  2.98T  2.40T  /mnt/data`

I ran this command to replicate the oldest monthly `zfs-auto-snap` snapshot available:

`zfs send -v -R zfs_pool01/data@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2015-04-01-0652 | ssh 192.168.254.5 zfs recv -F zfs_pool01/Van_backup/data`

And (after some days) here is the result of `zfs list` in the remote ZFS:

`NAME                        USED   AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT`
`zfs_pool01/Van_backup/data  1.10T  9.73T  1.10T  /mnt/backup/Van/data`

What is puzzling me is that I can't actually see any data in `/mnt/backup/Van/data` or `zfs_pool01/`, nor under any of the hidden `.zfs` directories.

`du -hs *` shows `512  Van`, which is basically 0 bytes.

And yet... and yet, there is ~1.1 TB of data existing somewhere?

I'm leery of attempting another zfs incremental send, if I can't find the first one.

Regards,

Eric P.

PS: I should note that `zfs-auto-snap` is disabled on the remote server's `zfs_pool01/Van_backup/data`.  No need to create unneeded snaps.

Comment: *I'm leery of attempting another zfs incremental send, if I can't find the first one.* Indeed. Is there anything at all on the receiving side? What does `zfs list -t all zfs_pool01` on the receiving side show?

Comment: Well, what do you know - it's there, just invisible.  
Which is properly the correct state for a snapshot:

zfs list -t all | grep -i Van

zfs_pool01/Van_backup  1.10T  9.67T    19K  /mnt/backup/Van
zfs_pool01/Van_backup/data 1.10T  9.67T  1.10T  /mnt/backup/Van/data
zfs_pool01/Van_backup/data@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2015-04-01-0652 0 - 1.10T -

Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: @AndrewHenle please do reply as an answer (and not a comment) so this question can me marked as answered - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @AndrewHenle, this question has been answered.

The copied snapshot is in place, but is invisible.  That is probably the correct state for a snapshot to be in:

This command:

```
zfs list -t all | grep -i Van
```

Shows these results:

```
zfs_pool01/Van_backup 1.10T 9.67T 19K /mnt/backup/Van
zfs_pool01/Van_backup/data 1.10T 9.67T 1.10T /mnt/backup/Van/data
zfs_pool01/Van_backup/data@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2015-04-01-0652 0 - 1.10T
```

So, it appears the snapshot is there and ready for restoration as needed.

Hope that helps anyone else who is confused!